# NEST ElasticSearch for Did you mean feature

Tags: c#, .net, linq, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to implement "Did you mean" feature like google in my windows desktop application.

I have created a POC which inserts "Name" and "Description" in my index say "MyIndex"

I am able to do full text search, but unable to do something like "Did you mean".

here is a code snipt that I found in NEST documentation and i am unable to understand it:

```
s => s
.Suggest(ss => ss
    .Term("my-term-suggest", t => t
        .MaxEdits(1)
        .MaxInspections(2)
        .MaxTermFrequency(3)
        .MinDocFrequency(4)
        .MinWordLength(5)
        .PrefixLength(6)
        .SuggestMode(SuggestMode.Always)
        .Analyzer("standard")
        .Field(p => p.Name)
        .ShardSize(7)
        .Size(8)
        .Text("hello world")
    )
    .Completion("my-completion-suggest", c => c
        .Contexts(ctxs => ctxs
            .Context("color",
                ctx => ctx.Context(Project.First.Suggest.Contexts.Values.SelectMany(v => v).First())
            )
        )
        .Fuzzy(f => f
            .Fuzziness(Fuzziness.Auto)
            .MinLength(1)
            .PrefixLength(2)
            .Transpositions()
            .UnicodeAware(false)
        )
        .Analyzer("simple")
        .Field(p => p.Suggest)
        .Size(8)
        .Prefix(Project.Instance.Name)
    )
    .Phrase("my-phrase-suggest", ph => ph
        .Collate(c => c
            .Query(q => q
                .Inline("{ \"match\": { \"{{field_name}}\": \"{{suggestion}}\" }}")
                .Params(p => p.Add("field_name", "title"))
            )
            .Prune()
        )
        .Confidence(10.1)
        .DirectGenerator(d => d
            .Field(p => p.Description)
        )
        .GramSize(1)
        .Field(p => p.Name)
        .Text("hello world")
        .RealWordErrorLikelihood(0.5)
    )
)
```

what is color, doing here?
Also what is this " `ctx => ctx.Context(Project.First.Suggest.Contexts.Values.SelectMany(v => v).First()`"

and this "`.Prefix(Project.Instance.Name)`".

Am I on the right path?
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The did you mean feature is more likely Term suggester (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-term.html)

Completion is autocompletion. When you write "so" in searchbox it will give you "sony", "soly" ..etc. So in this case you wont need this feature.
(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html)

Phrase is advanced Term suggester, phrase gives you to choice pre-selected suggestions with a mapping as document says
(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-phrase.html)

You need this snippet in nest

```
s => s
.Suggest(ss => ss
    .Term("my-term-suggest", t => t
        .MaxEdits(1)
        .MaxInspections(2)
        .MaxTermFrequency(3)
        .MinDocFrequency(4)
        .MinWordLength(5)
        .PrefixLength(6)
        .SuggestMode(SuggestMode.Always)
        .Analyzer("standard")
        .Field(p => p.Name)
        .ShardSize(7)
        .Size(8)
        .Text("hello world")
    ))
```